# Central limit theorem proof for ($\bar{x}_n - \mu$)

Tags: self-study, variance, arithmetic

It's probably very simple but I am stuck to prove the variance of the central limit theorem in this case

$x_{1}, x_{2}, \ldots x_{n}$ random sample. $E\left(x_{i}\right)=\mu, \operatorname{Var}\left(x_{i}\right)=\sigma^{2}$ $E\left(\bar{x}_{n}\right)=\mu \quad \operatorname{Var}\left(\bar{x}_{n}\right)=\sigma^{2} / n \quad \bar{x}_{n}$ approx. $N\left(\mu, \sigma^{2} / n\right)$ n large

- $\bar{x}_{n}-\mu \quad: \quad E\left(\bar{x}_{n}-\mu\right)=0 \quad \operatorname{Var}\left(\bar{x}_{n}-\mu\right)=\sigma^{2} / n$

I started doing something like

$$
\begin{aligned}
Var(\bar{x}_n - \mu) &= E((\bar{x}_n - \mu) - E(\bar{x}_n - \mu))^2\\
&= E((\bar{x}_n - \mu))^2\\
&= E((\bar{x}_n^2 - 2 \bar{x}_n \mu + \mu^2))\\
&= E(\bar{x}_n^2) - 2\mu^2 + \mu^2\\
&= E(\bar{x}_n^2) -\mu^2\\
\end{aligned}
$$
Which is not correct

Comment: Your formula for the variance is wrong.